# I can't reset Active Directory user password by the admin using C# .NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, active-directory, directoryentry, userprincipal

I'm Trying to reset active directory user password by .NET core web API but always return below exception, even if I put very complex password

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PasswordException:
> 'The password does not meet   the password policy requirements.
> Check the minimum password length, password complexity
> and password history requirements. (0x800708C5)'

I tried both ways (`DirectoryEntry` and the new one) but I get the same exception.

Here is my code, but I think

```
public bool ResetPassword(string oldPassword, string newPassword, string userNameI)
{
    /*  // set up domain context
    PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, LDAP_PATH, userName, password);

    if (context != null)
    {
        // find the user you want to delete
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userNameI);

        if (user != null)
        {
            user.Enabled = true;
            user.ChangePassword(oldPassword,newPassword);
            user.ExpirePasswordNow();
            user.Save();

            return true;
        }
    }*/

    /*  
    var entry = new DirectoryEntry
                    {
                        Path = "LDAP://MyIP",
                        Username = userName,
                        Password = password
                    };

    using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
    {
        searcher.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + userNameI + ")";

        var result = searcher.FindOne();

        var user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

        user.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { oldPassword.Trim(), newPassword.Trim() });
        user.CommitChanges();

        return true;
    }
    */

    using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "LDAPIP", userName, password))
    {
        using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userNameI))
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                user.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);
                user.Save();

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Username not found: {0}", userNameI));
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do not set any policy, the password follows the default policy, and your modified password needs to comply with this policy.  Please check this document: [Azure AD password policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-password-ban-bad-combined-policy#azure-ad-password-policies).

Comment: The same password that I can't set by code I can set it manually on the server, so I don't think the issue is related to the password policy, the appeared exception is not accurate I guess.

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint to see if the changed password is what you expect? Maybe it's not the password style you set after some processing.

Comment: Yes I did, and I tried to use validCredintioal and the provided password it's working fine, only the issue in resetting password

Comment: Note that you're "changing" the password, not "resetting". Resetting (`SetPassword`) is an administrative task where you set the password without knowing the old password.

Comment: One of the requirements is that there is a minimum password age. Has the password been already changed or reset in the last 24 hours? (or whatever the minimum password age is on your domain)

Comment: @GabrielLuci Yes after checking the reset password, it's working now but the change password is not, but I'm trying to change the password from the admin user, is that possible for a password policy exception?

Comment: Only the password complexity policy is required when resetting the password, not the password history or minimum password age. So if you can reset, but can't change, then the issue is either the password history or the minimum password age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is working fine, the Old password is not needed in resetting password and account owner user name is needed :

```
        public bool ResetPassword(string newPassword, string accountOwneruserName /*user name for the user that you want to change his password*/)
        {

            using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "17x.xx.xx.x" /*Active Directory server Ip*/, adminUserName, adminPassword ))
            {
                using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, accountOwneruserName))
                {

                    if (user != null)
                    {
                  
                        user.SetPassword(newPassword.Trim());
                        user.Save();
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception(string.Format("Username not found: {0}", accountOwneruserName));
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

        }
```